# How can I read a number as user input?

Tags: minibuffer, numbers, read

I would like a user to input a number using the minibuffer.  What function should I call and how should it be used?

Comment: You should try this: `C-h f read- TAB`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What function should I call

`read-number`

> how should it be used

You can call it directly, e.g., `(read-number "")`.

But if you are writing a function, I recommend you put `(interactive "n")` (or similar form) in your function body.